# python list how to changed to dict?

Tags: python

I have a list, and I want it to be dict.

i have a list:

```py
[[[(1, 1.96),
   (2, 0.98),
   (3, 0.6533),
   (4, 0.49),
   (5, 0.392),
   (6, 0.3267),
   (7, 0.28)]],
 [[(1, 10.01),
   (2, 7.48),
   (3, 4.9867),
   (4, 3.74),
   (5, 2.992),
   (6, 2.4933),
   (7, 2.1372)]]]
```

how to changed to:

```py
{1: [1.96, 0.98, 0.6533, 0.49, 0.392, 0.3267, 0.28], 2: [...], 3:[...], ...}
```

this dict key is the first element of the tuple in the list

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: How are the keys `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. related to the original data? If you're using the list indexes, shouldn't it be `0`, `1`, `2`, ...?

Comment: Why does the original data have the lists nested inside another list?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as "answered", please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the limited information you've given in the question, here is a solution:

```
>>> { i: [j[1] for j in v[0]] for i, v in enumerate(l) }
{0: [1.96, 0.98, 0.6533, 0.49, 0.392, 0.3267, 0.28], 1: [10.01, 7.48, 4.9867, 3.74, 2.992, 2.4933, 2.1372]}
```

But please in the future specify more, and show what you've already tried!

Comment: This dict key is the first element of the tuple in the list.

Comment: This dict key is the first element of the tuple in the list.

Comment: But that's not what your example does

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> data = [[[(1, 1.96),
...    (2, 0.98),
...    (3, 0.6533),
...    (4, 0.49),
...    (5, 0.392),
...    (6, 0.3267),
...    (7, 0.28)]],
...  [[(1, 10.01),
...    (2, 7.48),
...    (3, 4.9867),
...    (4, 3.74),
...    (5, 2.992),
...    (6, 2.4933),
...    (7, 2.1372)]]]
>>> d = {i: list(zip(*val[0]))[1] for i, val in enumerate(data, 1)}
>>> pprint(d)
{1: (1.96, 0.98, 0.6533, 0.49, 0.392, 0.3267, 0.28),
 2: (10.01, 7.48, 4.9867, 3.74, 2.992, 2.4933, 2.1372)}
```